# How to create recurring tasks via the Task component in the Account record page?

Tags: lightning, page-layout, account, component, task-recurrence

I have the Create Recurring Series of Tasks checkbox enabled in the Task component of the create new Task in the panel on the Account record page.

[image]I need to know how to create recurring tasks as the checkbox itself does not show the `Frequency`, the `Repeat`, the `Start/End date` options for creating a recurring tasks?

Please advise why if the Create Recurring Series is checked does not show the recurring options for creating recurring tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312874&type=1&mode=1) Salesforce Knowledge Article, you can't create a recurring task using Global or custom action.

> In order for the 'Create Recurring Series of Tasks' checkbox to
> display during the Task creation process, the 'Delete Series' and
> 'View Series' actions must be added to the Mobile & Lightning Action
> section of the page.
>
> Since it isn't possible to add these buttons to an Action layout, it
> is not possible to display 'Create Recurring Series of Tasks' on the
> Action layout.

There is one [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003SPjQAM) also available, you can vote for this.

As an alternative, you can add Open Activity related list in your page and create recurring Task from there.